# Title bar height of the form is reduced on maximized state

Tags: forms, winforms

I have noticed that the height of title bar in the form get reduced when the form is in maximized state. In normal state, the title bar height is 32 pixels(approximately). When maximized it is reduced to 26 pixels(approximately). Also the space between the icon and the borders (left ad top) get reduced.

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this changes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the default behavior for the maximized window, it hides the"resizing" borders (or rather places those borders out of the screen). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14667605/5922736) provides more details.