# How to remove wsNormal fullscreen form title bar content offset?

Tags: delphi, windows-10, vcl, titlebar

When maximizing a Form via WindowState:=wsMaximized, the title bar looks like this:

[image: Maximized form with a "normal" title bar]

When setting the form to WindowState:=wsNormal and setting the form size manualy to a fullscreen state, the content of the frame is identical but the title bar is slightly moved.

[image]

The `wsNormal` form Rect on a 800*600 screen to simulate a `wsMaxed` form is TRect(-8,-8,808,608).
(See [this question why the difference of the size is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667558))

My Question:
How can i fix the moved title bar content for the wsNormal window, so it would look correct like the following mock up?

[image]

Simple example form with one button, which reproduces both form states.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FState: Integer;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    procedure WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Message: TWMGetMinMaxInfo); message WM_GETMINMAXINFO;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LBRect: TRect;
begin
  LBRect  := Screen.Monitors[0].BoundsRect;

  case FState of
    0:
    begin
      WindowState := wsMaximized;
    end;
    1:
    begin
      WindowState := wsNormal;
      LBRect := Screen.Monitors[0].WorkareaRect;
      LBRect.Inflate(8,8); //offset 8 for a form with bsSizeable
      BoundsRect := LBRect;
    end;
  end;

  Inc(FState);
  FState := FState mod 2;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Message: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
begin
  //slightly smaller MaxTrackSize would prevent the wsNormal form the fully cover the screen on the right side
  Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxTrackSize := Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxSize;
end;

end.
```

Edit1:

To clarify why this might be usefull:
We have a multi-monitor set up with identical resolution screens and want to span the form over this verly large "virtual screen. The desktop can not be unified to one large screen via e.g. AMDs Virtual Destkop settings.

The problem occurs because the title bar rect of a maximized Form has a slightly smaller height than a non-maximized form title bar.

Also, there is a need for the negative positions and enlarged size, [caused by the (backwards compatible) way windows handles the border calculations and positioning.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120326-00/?p=8003/) The actual offset/enlargement comes from the chosen borderstyle.

Comment: You locate the form at a negative offset and want that the caption won't move with it. I can't guess what kind of solution do you hope for, but the caption will stick to the window at all times. My solution would be to use a maximized window instead of a mock up. If you found yourself in a situation that you can't use a maximized window, you may want to ask about that problem instead.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to specify the caption rect, so it would be equal to the rect in wsMaximized state.

Comment: Nope, the caption will be stuck where it is now. Maybe you'd want to mock the caption too.

Comment: This makes no sense. It works right when you use `wsMaximized`, so why aren't you just using `wsMaximized`? Why are you using `wsNormal` and then oversizing the form to exceed the screen size? If you want the behavior of a maximized window, maximize the window and let the OS do its job.

Comment: @Ken White Because we have some multi monitor setups without a virtual desktop covering all of them. Using wsMaximized will max the form to one screen. Using wsNormal allows to cover all screens.

Comment: What about setting `Top` to -2 instead of -8?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg Then the client area would also move by 6 pixel and would not be equal to the maxed forms area.

Comment: Actually the content of the title bar is not necessarily the same for maximised and normal. Maybe it depends on the style, but certainly when I tried your example there is physically more white under the title text in normal mode than in maximised.

Comment: @Dsm And that is exactly my problem. I would love to have a way to define the title bars rect, to force it to be drawn in a smaller region and to look similar. But i did not found anything, thats why i am searching for a solution here.

Comment: I have also been looking and the answer may be styles. If you create your own style as a copy of the one you are using and switch to it when 'normalising', the bitmap style editor allows you to change Title Top, Title Bottom and caption left, which would seem to allow you to do what you want - although I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, i found a way to reach the Goal for the described Scenario with minimal effort. This does not answer the question itself, it will only reach the goal.

When a form is created and also when it is maximized (by either the user or setting the forms WindowState to `wsMaximized`), the window message `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` gets send.

With sending `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, the Form will be asked about its desired position and size in a maximized situation.

Here, we can override windows default positioning and e.g. span a maximized view over multiple screens by setting the values accordingly.

When analyzing the default values sent via `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message, the values will have an offset of 8 in each dimension.

[The offset was necessary on older Windows OS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120326-00/?p=8003/) to tell the window manager to hide the borderstyle outside of the current screens view, and would also result in [edge bleeding on multi-monitor setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936906). 
The edge bleeding also occurs nowadays, when the WindowState is is set to `wsNormal`.

The Offset will also tell Windows Window Manager to reduce the title bars size when it is docked to the top AND to render the title bar content correctly (**which is the goal we searched for**).

See the following example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    FState: Integer;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    procedure WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Message: TWMGetMinMaxInfo); message WM_GETMINMAXINFO;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case FState of
    0:
    begin
      WindowState := wsMaximized;
    end;
    1:
    begin
      WindowState := wsNormal;
      BoundsRect := TRect.Create(100,-8,300,192);
    end;
    2:
    begin
      WindowState := wsMaximized;
    end;
    3:
    begin
      WindowState := wsNormal;
      BoundsRect := TRect.Create(100,0,300,200);
    end;
    4:
    begin
      WindowState := wsMaximized;
    end;
    5:
    begin
      WindowState := wsNormal;
      BoundsRect := TRect.Create(100,100,300,300);
    end;
  end;

  Inc(FState);
  FState := FState mod 6;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMGetMinMaxInfo(var Message: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
begin
case FState of
  0, 1:
  begin
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxPosition.SetLocation(100,-8);
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxSize.SetLocation(200,200);
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxTrackSize := Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxSize;
    inherited;
  end;
  2, 3:
  begin
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxPosition.SetLocation(100,0);
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxSize.SetLocation(200,200);
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxTrackSize := Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxSize;
    inherited;
  end;
  4, 5:
  begin
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxPosition.SetLocation(100,100);
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxSize.SetLocation(200,200);
    Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxTrackSize := Message.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxSize;
    inherited;
  end;
end;

end;

end.
```

FYI: `var Message: TWMGetMinMaxInfo` seems to be persistent for the forms lifetime.

On state 0, the form is slightly moved into the top, which tells the window manager to render this forms title slightly smaller. This is the default behaviour for maximized forms **and the optical result i searched for**.

State 1 will show the problem i had, and the other states will show you that positioning a maximized form anywhere is possible AND that the title bar will have the default size when it is not cutting a screens edge.

If you want to know what offsets to pick for your TForm, you can ask windows by using [AdjustWindowRectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632667(v=vs.85).aspx) with your chosen styles and main menu informations. (See: VCL.Forms.pas, `TCustomForm.GetClientRect` implementation)

Comment: > *" the values will have an offset of 8 in each dimension."* - This is incorrect. The actual offsets are the non client metrics `SM_CXFRAME` and `SM_CYFRAME`, horizontally and vertically respectively.

Comment: You have answered the question you should have ask. This answer would be better suited to a question "how can I customize my window's maximized position" or something like it. It would probably be a duplicate but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: The offset depends on the chosen borderstyle. Give it a try. For bsSingle, the offset will be 3.

Comment: And yes, the anwser is kind of to a different question. But i would prefer to have a solution for the asked question, if there is one. Maybe it is via custom styles, as suggested by Dsm.

Comment: Yes of course, your post is about a window with a sizing border, hence the offset is SM_C[X|Y]YFRAME. The actual offset for a single bordered window is SM_C[X|Y]FIXEDFRAME, rather than 3.

Comment: Custom styles is no different than mocking up a caption in any way you can imagine, you can draw anything you like. It wouldn't be an answer to have the actual caption at a different place than it is now.

Comment: Anyway, the value is an observation and is about having an offset. There may be more suitable ways to get the exact value for a arbitrary form and style. E.g. calling AdjustWindowRectEx with a zeroed rect will give you the correct x/y offset via right/bottom values. So you do not need to check the styles and pick the correct metric for it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard caption of an API window is fixed, you cannot do anything to alter its position or size.